# sql server stored procedure to update records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have tried to create a stored procedure that takes values from my program and inserts it into specific columns in a table.
I keep getting an error of incorrect syntax in the stored procedure but cannot figure out why?
The code from program:

```
            commandObj.CommandText = "sp_insert_profileDetails"

            commandObj.Parameters.Clear()

            Dim m_param As SqlParameter

            m_param = commandObj.Parameters.Add("@authorId", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)
            m_param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            m_param.Value = foundProfiles.Item(i)


            m_param = commandObj.Parameters.Add("@age", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)
            m_param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            m_param.Value = faceProfileAge.Item(i)

            m_param = commandObj.Parameters.Add("@gender", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)
            m_param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            m_param.Value = faceProfileSex.Item(i)

            m_param = commandObj.Parameters.Add("@locale", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)
            m_param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            m_param.Value = faceProfileLocation.Item(i)

            m_param = commandObj.Parameters.Add("@pic", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)
            m_param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            m_param.Value = faceProfilePic.Item(i)

            Dim recordsAffected As Integer = commandObj.ExecuteNonQuery
            Return recordsAffected



ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_insert_profileDetails]
@authorId nvarchar(100),
@age nvarchar(50),
@gender nvarchar(50),
@locale nvarchar(50),
@pic nvarchar(100)

AS 
  Begin
  set nocount on
  update [dbo].ProfileFeed
  set [age] = @age,
      [sex] = @gender,
      [locale] = @locale,
      [pic] = @pic
  where 
      [authorId] = @authorId
  end
```

Any assistance appreciated?

Comment: What's the error? Can you copy paste it here?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but prefixing your sprocs with sp_ is discouraged by MS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669.aspx

Comment: A fussy point, unless you know exactly what you're doing and why, you really don't want to prefix your procedures with "sp_".  SQL does some extra processing for all sp_ procedures, and this could trip you up over time.  (Detailed explanation can be found in BOL.)

Comment: Thanks Chris and Phillip...will keep that in mind and change it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm missing a few lines of code to be sure, but....

Did you specify that the commandObj.CommandType is System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure?

If you forget to set this, .NET will treat it as System.Data.CommandType.Text by default, and the database will throw an Incorrect Syntax error..

Comment: I did forget to do that, let me try it again...thanks..will post back

Comment: My pleasure.  Glad to be of assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are actually inserting any records into the database.

The stored procedure states:

```
  update [dbo].ProfileFeed
  set [age] = @age,
      [sex] = @gender,
      [locale] = @locale,
      [pic] = @pic
  where 
      [authorId] = @authorId
  end
```

Yet the SP is named `[dbo].[sp_insert_profileDetails]`

Did you mean to write "`insert into [dbo].ProfileFeed`" instead of "`update`"?

Comment: I am not trying to add new records, I am trying to update existing record columns. So where the authorId matches that is where those columns need to be updated.